# VSCODE powershell terminal clickable link

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

in the terminal(powershell integrated terminal) i display with format-table the output of a deployment (pl1 code).

The warnings etc. are displayed with the line number where they appear. Is it possible to make a clickable link(on the whole line with the warning or just on the line number) to directly jump to the line in the source code?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want to be clickable?

Comment: Can do a blackened screenshot tomorrow (security policies). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it is possible by just writing the full

```
C:\xxx\_yyy\zzzz\tttt\1111\SRCFILE.PLI:10:4
```

or relative path followed by position

```
..\zzzz\tttt\1111\SRCFILE.PLI:10:4
```